ACH Stripe one time payment while checkout - ionic Front end - Codeigniter 4 backend via API
I'm trying to add ACH payment during checkout. in ionic I created custom form to collect user Routing number and bank account number and account holder name. and in ionic ts using Publishable key I create token using "this.stripe.createBankAccountToken(bstripeBankDetails)" and pass the details in API file.
Ionic code:
this.stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_51P5kD0...');

                const bstripeBankDetails = {
                    "routing_number": '110000000',
                    "account_number": '000123456789',
                    "account_holder_name": 'John Smith', // optional
                    "account_holder_type": 'individual', // optional
                    "currency": 'USD',
                   "country": 'US'
                }
               
                this.stripe.createBankAccountToken(bstripeBankDetails)
                    .then(token => {
                        console.log(token);
                        console.log(token['bank_account']['id']);
                        this.stripeError = "";
                        //this.loaderService.hide();
                        this.stripeBankToken = token['id'];
                        this.stripeBankAccount = token['bank_account']['id'];
                        console.log(this.stripeBankToken);
                        console.log(this.stripeBankAccount);
                        //this.saveorder(); //actual function
                        //this.teststrip();
                        // For testing I'm passing data in this API
                        let formData = {
                            "banktoken"     : token['id'],
                            "bankaccount"   : token['bank_account']['id'],
                        }
                        this.api.post("stripe_data.php", formData).subscribe((data: any) => {
                            console.log("RESULT", data);
                        });
                        
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error("Stripe error 1 - ", error.message);
                        console.error("Stripe error - ", error);
                        // this.stripeError = error.message;
                        this.stripeError = error;
                        this.loaderService.hide();
                        this.loaderService.showToast(this.stripeError);
                        return false;
                    });

Backend API code:
// ACH payment
if($payment_type == 'ach')
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51P5k...');
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'description' => 'Example customer',
        'source' => $banktoken
    ]);
    //echo "bank_account<pre>"; print_r($customer->id);
    try {
        // Create a customer with the bank token
                // **** some docs says we have bank details from frondend so no need to "retrieveSource" ******* //   
        // Retrieve the bank account source
        //$bank_account = \Stripe\Customer::retrieveSource($customer->id, $bankaccount);
        //echo "bank_account<pre>"; print_r($bank_account);
        // Verify the bank account
        //$verification = $bankaccount->verify(['amounts' => [32, 45]]);
        //echo "verification<pre>"; print_r($verification);exit;
              //**** not sure do we need to make PaymentIntent or charges. but while charge it's working but PaymentIntent showing error.
        $payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'amount' => 1000, // Amount in cents
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'payment_method_types' => ['ach_debit'],
            'payment_method' => $bankaccount,
            'confirm' => true,
        ]);
        echo "bank_account<pre>"; print_r($payment_intent);
        // Payment Intent was successful
        echo "Payment Intent successful: " . $payment_intent->id;
        //exit;
        // $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_51P....');
        // $total = $_POST["total"];
        // $payment = $stripe->charges->create([
        //  'amount' => $total * 100,
        //  'currency' => 'usd',
        //  'customer' => $customer->id,
        // ]);
        // $transactionID = $payment->id;
        //echo "payment<pre>"; print_r($payment->id);exit;
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
        //echo 'Stripe Error: ' . $e->getError()->message;
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $transaction_id = '';
        array_push($myarray,array('stripemessage' => $error,
        "success"=>0
        ));
        echo json_encode($myArray);
        exit;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $transaction_id = '';
        array_push($myarray,array('message' => $error,
        "success"=>0
        ));
        echo json_encode($myArray);
        exit;
    }
}
echo "transID::".$transactionID;exit;

FYI: I'm stripe test account and I enabled ACH Direct Debit in path: settings>payments>payment methods.
For web site I'm using stripe.com prebuild code page via redirect method so user can enter bank details in stripe form and pay later using webhook getting payment status. but in ionic we can't use "Secret key" so made token using bank details and pass it to backend.

Here, Please someone tell me what are the steps I need to take to make ACH payment?
Stripe doc say's it take 2 days for ACH payment. so I guess we need to use PaymentIntent instead of charges.
Do we need to verifiy bank in stripe?
$verification = $bankaccount->verify(['amounts' => [32, 45]]);
how to check status of payment using micro deposits or it's direct debit from bank?
NOTE: Can't find new dox for ACH using token. old docs says - "Deprecated"
refer this too
refers links


Tokens API is deprecated and no longer recommended. I'd recommend checking the direct API integration guide for ACH direct debit here

Thanks for the reply. I'm using ionic as frontend. how to use direct API here? in the doc they give js sample only how to do it in ionic?
in your link page: 4. Collect payment method details

"Direct API for web only. how to use it in ionic app. here i can't redirect to stripe right?"

For the timing portion "takes 2 days for ACH payment".  That's more variable than you might think.  There are two sets of ACH windows to submit transactions, SameDay and NextDay.  If you submit before Noon EST and your Merchant Account at Stripe/Ionic is set for the SameDay window it will shave a day off of your total time.  Also, the time it takes is risk dependent, faster funding is riskier to the processor due to the return window, and will probably cost more, but it's possible to have them change it.  This would be a call to your account manager to request that.
